# Web app throws ERROR 500 on load, but only if compiled by Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war

When I package a Java "dynamic web project" in Eclipse for export, the created WAR can be launched onto a server and the app will load correctly.

However, if I try and build my project with Maven (w/ and w/o Jenkins), the build will claim it succeeded but the resulting war is messed up somehow because attempting to load my app will give me this error:

```
**HTTP Status 500 - exception**

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor cannot be cast to org.apache.AnnotationProcessor
.blah blah blah Stacktrace goes here blah blah....

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor cannot be cast to org.apache.AnnotationProcessor
. blah blah blah  Stacktrace goes here blah blah....
```

I've read that this can be caused by a mismatch of Tomcat Versions between what's on the server and what's in my POM, but I've made sure that both are v6.0.26.

Is there something else that could be causing this - something else with my POM, my Maven configuration, or something completely different?

Comment: Which JARs do you find in `your.war/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: If you don't get an answer, I'd compare the differences between the two wars when eclipse makes it vs when maven does.

Comment: @lefloh None because I read that having any there can also cause this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely caused by version incompatibility. Your server may contain jars that are brought in different versions by maven eg. the server contains a commons-util-1.1.jar and your maven downloads a commons-util-1.2.jar to you WEB-INF/lib/

Try to compare your two WEB-INF/lib/ directories (the one coming from eclipse and the one from maven).

Searching google for the message "DefaultAnnotationProcessor cannot be cast to org.apache.AnnotationProcessor" could help you find which jar causes the issue and concentrate on it (but it may be not the only one, a jar may hide another jar :-) )

I recommend using TotalCommander (http://www.ghisler.com/) to compare directories with all sudirs and files to get directly what is different with one command. (you can also use it to search for a class in all jars)

Best Regards,
Zied Hamdi - http://1vu.fr

Comment: Thank you for your help!

It turns out that it was a server configuration problem! I got it working now. :)